# Ubuntu 20.04 Nautilus Samba Share Settings

Tags: nautilus, samba

I am trying to workout where the central Nautilus Samaba share settings are located.

I have shared some folders using Nautilus, but cannot see these changes being reflected in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

When I call `smbstatus` I don't get any results, however when I run `smbclient -L localhost` I can see my shares being listed.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a central settings location (gui or file) that I can see and manage all the shares I've setup through Nautilus? It seems unusual that I would have to remember the share locations in Nautilus, and have to navigate to them individually to be able to change their settings.
2. How do the Nautilus configured shares handle user access? I can authenticate to the shares with my current user, but don't recall setting up any smbpasswd users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shares created in Nautilus are Samba Usershares.

Overall control over how usershares are implemented is in smb.conf but the share definitions themselves are not.

To see how all these nautilus shares are configured you can run the following command:

```
net usershare info --long
```

And the actual share definitions are represented by files under:

```
/var/lib/samba/usershares
```